# Replace a local file with a downloaded one in PHP

Tags: php

I have been looking a this function:

> [bool **move_uploaded_file** ( string $filename , string $destination )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

What this does is it checks if the file can be overwritten and does it. Now my problem is the following:

> This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is
>   a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST
>   upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the
>   filename given by destination.

When I fill in a url as the filename, it return false. Is there another function I could use to replace a local file with one from a url. **They both have the name name**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use [`copy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) for this purpose. `move_uploaded_file` is unsuitable because the source file has not been uploaded through a POST request (i.e. most commonly through a form submission to your script).

Comment: Oh so simple, wow. Sorry for asking this. Will accept in a few minutes.

Comment: @SaifBechan: No worries. This is possible because of PHP's [built-in protocol wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php); you might want to have a look.